# Image and Kernel of Polynomial Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $D: P\Rightarrow$ $P$  and $G: P\Rightarrow$ $P$ be linear transformations where, 
$D(p)=p'$ and $G(p)=q, $$q(x)=xp(x)$.
How do I find $D$ and $G$'s image and kernel?

Comment: What have you tried so far for each part of the question?

Comment: I have tried to represent their matrices, but I am a bit unsure how to do it due to not knowing the polynomial degree. Linear algebra is quite new for me.

Comment: Think about how the image and kernel are defined in general as opposed to thinking about this problem in the context of matrices.  What is the general definition for the kernel of a linear mapping?  That should help you think about how to begin the problem.

Comment: So ker D will then be when the derivative of the polynomial equals zero? If so, how would I present it mathematically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to math SE. On your next posts, please add any progress you have made on the problem, people here are a little peculiar on seeing that you have actually tried something. Anyway, I'm not:

I'd start by showing that these maps are actually linear (you can do it as an exercise). Now, for the kernel of $D$, it is $\text{Ker}(D)=\{p(x): p'(x)=0\}$, therefore the kernel consists of the constant polynomials, that is $\text{Ker}(D)=\{p(x): \text{ deg}(p(x))=0\}$. As about the image, our intuition says "it is probably the whole space of polynomials"; so let's try proving this: indeed, take $p(x)=a_0+\dots+a_nx^n$ and "integrate" it: consider the polynomial $q(x)=a_0x+\frac{a_1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}$. Then $D(q(x))=p(x)$ and our intuition was right.

About $G$, let's start with the kernel: if $p(x)\in\text{ker}(G)$, then $xp(x)=0$; if $p(x)$ is not identically zero, then $xp(x)$ has at most $deg(p(x))+1$ roots. Now i assume these are real/complex polynomials, hence we cant have $xp(x)=0$. Therefore $p(x)=0$ and $G$ is 1-1. About the image, it obviously consists of all polynomials of the form $a_0x+a_1x^2+\dots+a_nx^{n+1}$, that is all the polynomials that have $0$ as a root.

Comment: Thank you both for nice explanations and tips for future posts.

Comment: If () is not identical to zero, why can't x be zero and then we have ()=0?

Comment: how can $x$ be identically $0$ when it is not? it is like asking why can't $1=2$

Comment: I thought that only () is not identically 0, and not x. like (0) would be a constant. I am probably just retarded.